# when try to excure procedure it said compliation error in oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I try to write select procedure in oracle.but it compile success,  when I try to execute it given error.

```
 set serveroutput on;
    CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE retrieve_decrypt(
        custid  in NUMBER,
        column_name in VARCHAR2,
        test_value OUT VARCHAR2
        ) 
        AS

   BEGIN
      -- enc_dec.decrypt(column_name,password) into  test_value from employees where custid=5;
        COMMIT;
   END;
/


set serveroutput on;
EXEC retrieve_decrypt(5,'creditcardno');
```

the error says ,

[image]

Comment: Thanks uma.  In the example you provided, it looks like the procedure requires three arguments, but only two were provided.  Have you tried running with three arguments, including the out parameter?

Comment: @alexgibbs nope. i try different way , i thin OUT not take as out put result ? (i need to run through Oreacle Sql Deverloprt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure retrieve_decrypt
  2    (custid      in number,
  3     column_name in varchar2,
  4     test_value out varchar2
  5    )
  6  as
  7  begin
  8    -- your code goes here
  9    null;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

This is how you call it (and get the error):

```
SQL> exec retrieve_decrypt(5, 'creditcardno');
BEGIN retrieve_decrypt(5, 'creditcardno'); END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'RETRIEVE_DECRYPT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL>
```

The cause of the error is:

- the procedure contains **3** parameters:

  - 2 of them are IN - you provided their values
  - 1 of them is OUT - you didn't provide it and got the error

Here's what you should have done: as the 3rd parameter is OUT, you'll have to DECLARE it:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_out varchar2(20);
  3  begin
  4    retrieve_decrypt(5, 'creditcardno', l_out);
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

`EXEC` you used is a SQL*Plus command so it might not work everywhere; `DECLARE-BEGIN-END` block will so I'd suggest you use it.

Alternatively, in SQL*Plus, it could be rewritten as

```
SQL> var l_out varchar2
SQL>
SQL> exec retrieve_decrypt(5, 'creditcardno', :l_out);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

but - once again - you'd better use `DECLARE-BEGIN-END` PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 1):

The initial error is:

> wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'RETRIEVE_DECRYPT'

The procedure requires 3 parameters.  You are only passing 2 (or apparently only 1, in the attempt that generated the error message shown).

Why do you also see the message "Usually a PL/SQL compilation error"?  The `EXEC` command in SQLPlus creates a PL/SQL block containing the text you provide, and sends that to Oracle for execution.  Oracle attempts to compile that PL/SQL block (just like it compiles the procedure when you create it).  In this case, the compilation fails because of the mismatch in the number of arguments.